# How can execute flexible search on japers reports?

Tags: mysql, search, sap-commerce-cloud

I'm beginner in hybris. I need to create a jasper reports, using flexible search and mysql server. But I can only use the sql query statement without flexible search in report file (Jrxml source file (.jrxml)).
How can I using the flexible search with mysql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you following the guide provided in Hybris Help for building a custom report? It can be found at https://help.hybris.com/6.3.0/hcd/8b6e40ee86691014b99eda29aebc9d84.html

In the interest of having a source of information in case the link ever becomes dead:

1. Go to `${HYBRIS_DIR}/hybris/bin/platform`
2. `setantenv.bat` for **Windows** or `. ./setantenv.sh` for **Unix/Linux**
3. Go to `${HYBRIS_DIR}/hybris/bin/ext-platform-optional/virtualjdbc`
4. Run the ant command `ant dist`
5. Go to `${HYBRIS_DIR}/hybris/temp/hybris/virtualjdbc`. You should have two files that have been generated here, **hybris-virtualjdbc.jar** and **vjdbc.jar**
6. You now need to copy these two files to `${HYBRIS_DIR}/hybris/bin/ext-platform-optional/virtualjdbc/lib`
7. Download the Jaspersoft Studio Tool at http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jaspersoft-studio
8. Install and Open Jaspersoft Studio
9. Go to **Tools > Options > iReport > Classpath**
10. Click **Add JAR** twice, each time selecting one of the newly copied JAR files (hybris-virtualjdbc.jar and vjdbc.jar)
11. Click **OK**
12. You now need to setup the Data Source, to do this:

    - Click on the Report Datasource icon ([image: Report Datasource Icon])
    - In the newly opened window, click **New**
    - Select **Database JDBC Connection** and click **Next**
    - On the next screen you may provide any name for your JDBC Connection
    - In the **JDBC Driver** field, make sure you type **de.hybris.vjdbc.VirtualDriver**
    - In the **JDBC URL** field, make sure you type **jdbc:hybris:sql:http:///virtualjdbc/service**, where  is the location of your application server (e.g. https://localhost:9002). Remember this will change with each environment!
    - Provide a Hybris User for the **Username** and **Password**. It may be worth using the admin user to begin with, but make sure you lock it down at a later stage to a user with less access, such as **vjdbcReportsUser**
    - Test the connection. Remember you will need the server up and running to be able to use vjdbc

From here onwards, you should be able to create a report using Flexible Search style syntax!

Comment: Thank for your help. @HarbyUK. I have resolved my proplem.

Comment: Could you tell me how to get dynamic properties of a itemtype? 
Example:
<attribute qualifier="note" type="java.lang.String">
 <modifiers optional="true"/>
 <persistence type="property"/>
    </attribute>
                <attribute qualifier="orderNumber" type="java.lang.String">
                    <persistence type="dynamic" attributeHandler="orderAdjustmentOrderNumberAttributeHandler"/>
                </attribute>


I can get the "note" property on my report but can't with "orderNumber".

Comment: No worries @LangKhach. As for the second question, I propose that you ask that as a separate question:

1. It helps the community if they have a similar issue, and won't be buried in a separate question. 2. You will be able to present the question with better formatiing. 3. It complies with the community guidelines. Please read the Help section at https://stackoverflow.com/help for more info